# Why am I getting duplicates in results? (DBpedia sparql query)

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I thought I was querying fine until I saw the result had some same events appearing a few times. Could anyone explain why?

Query:

```
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?event ?eventLabel

WHERE
  { ?event  a             dbo:MilitaryConflict ;
    dbo:date  ?date   .

FILTER ( ?date >= "1918-01-01"^^xsd:date && ?date <= "2018-12-31"^^xsd:date ).
FILTER(LANG(?eventLabel) = "nl").
OPTIONAL { ?event rdfs:label ?eventLabel.}}
```

Result:

http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX++dbo%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%23SELECT+++++%28+COUNT+%28DISTINCT+%3Fevent%29+AS+%3Fcnt+%29%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fevent+%3FeventLabel%0D%0A%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A++%7B+%3Fevent++a+++++++++++++dbo%3AMilitaryConflict+%3B%0D%0A++++dbo%3Adate++%3Fdate+++.%0D%0A%0D%0A++++FILTER+%28+%3Fdate+%3E%3D+%221918-01-01%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate+%26%26+%3Fdate+%3C%3D+%222018-12-31%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate+%29.%0D%0A++++FILTER%28LANG%28%3FeventLabel%29+%3D+%22nl%22%29.%0D%0A+++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fevent+rdfs%3Alabel+%3FeventLabel.%7D%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+

Comment: You should already know the purpose of the `DISTINCT` operator given that you used it already in previous queries ... and if you ask why, that's the nature of SPARQL, it returns a single "row" for each matching combination. Look at some of the events, they have multiple dates, thus, there are multiple RDF triple that match the query.

Comment: Shorter answer, `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: By the way, you won't find any event of 2017 and 2018 at this SPARQL endpoint.

Comment: OH thanks! :D Fog is off my head now. Obviously I was using DISTINCT for count, but not for this query.

Comment: Okay :) Do you have any clue why http://events.dbpedia.org/sparql won't work, though? I checked it for 2 weeks, and it's always offline. But it shouldn't matter that I query on http://dbpedia.org/sparql here instead, right...? Sorry for all the silly questions :D

Comment: No, not really. Looking at the [datasets page](http://events.dbpedia.org/dataset/), not sure if it's still maintained. TallTed already opened a [Github issue](https://github.com/dbpedia/events/issues/1). Other than that, you should write to the DBpedia community, either on the mailing list or maybe Twitter or something

Comment: But as I said before, the public DBpedia endpoint is outdated. Last release is from 2016, so you won't find any event after 2016 there. DBpedia Live is an alternative endpoint being almost in sync with the Wikipedia

Comment: I am okay without data of last few years. I will use the whole time periods or last 100 years. I was just not sure if dbpedia.org/sparql would function the same for events so I wanted to ask xD (no idea how events.dbpedia.org/sparql used to look...). And I wrote DBpedia a message 2? weeks ago about the event data but no reply.

Comment: "No, not really" as in no it doesn't matter that I use the dbpedia.org/sparql, I guess? Anyway thanks for all the help :)

Comment: No, I meant I don't know why the service is down. But I showed you some links, one of them leading to a Github issue some days ago.

Comment: I don not know whether the event data is loaded into dbpedia.org/sparql - I don't think so.

Comment: belle -- To what address did you send your message of ~2 weeks ago? I subscribe to several DBpedia-related mailing lists, and can find no sign of such a message. The only place I know of that's focused on the DBpedia Events endpoint, is the github project where I logged [the issue](https://github.com/dbpedia/events/issues/1) @AKSW referenced, and I believe that's the most likely place for you to get a relevant response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eliminate duplicate rows --

```
SELECT ?event ?eventLabel
```

-- should be made --

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?event ?eventLabel
```